# VB .net asp label undefined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I want to  set asp label to catch Cookie content,

I set

```
<p><asp:Label ID="lblUserID" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
```

in USERINFO.aspx

then set

```
Public Class USERINFO
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If (Request.Cookies("userInfo")("vID") IsNot Nothing) Then
                lblUserID.Text = Request.Cookies("userInfo")("vID").ToString
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

in USERINFO.aspx.vb

But got visual studio alert :lblUserID not defined

What should I do to connect the label correctly ?

Comment: You could try adding another label, saving the file, and see if the new label is recognised. Or look in the .designer file to check if the label is created properly.

Comment: If you suggesting that the code can't compile? then you HAVE to show more markup. That label should work, but if the label is nested inside of a repeater, or gridview, then you have to reference the label (or controls) in a different way. You need to show more of the markup and show were/how you placed the label on the web page. Also, any particular reason why you not storing values in session(), or even better ViewState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  @Andrew Morton, I solve the problem.
My issue is caused by that I didn't declare lblUserID in in USERINFO.aspx.designer.vb,
I also didn't wrote the Inherits tag in USERINFO.aspx like

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="USERINFO.aspx.vb" **Inherits="MyProject.USERINFO"** %>
```

Correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly, but you may still double-check if there's no typo in design and code-behind files.

Also, I noticed you're using ToString without parentheses, which is not correct. Please change it to -

```
lblUserID.Text = Request.Cookies("userInfo")("vID").ToString()
```